# How to convert to dynamic type/ apply multiple functions on same 'pack' in KQL/Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, adx

I am absolutely in love with ADX time series capabilities; having worked tons on sensor data with Python. Below are the requirements for my case:

1. Handle Sensor data tags at different frequencies -- bring them to all to 1 sec frequency (if in milliseconds, aggregate over a 1sec interval)
2. Convert stacked data to unstacked data.
3. Join with another dataset which has multiple "string-labels" by timestamp, after unstack.
4. Do linear interpolation on some columns, and forward fill in others (around 10-12 in all).

I think with below query I have gotten the first three done; but unable to use `series_fill_linear` directly on column. The docs say this function requires a `dynamic` type as input. The error message is helpful:
`series_fill_linear(): argument #1 was not of an expected data type: dynamic`

Is it possible to apply `series_fill_linear` where I'm already using `pack` instead of using `pack` again. How can I apply this function selectively by Tag; and make my overall query more readable?  It's important to note that only `sensor_data` table requires both `series_fill_linear` and `series_fill_forward`; `label_data` only requires `series_fill_forward`.

List item

```
sensor_data
    | where timestamp > datetime(2020-11-24 00:59:59) and timestamp <datetime(2020-11-24 12:00:00) 
    | where device_number =='PRESSURE_599' 
    | where tag_name in ("tag1", "tag2", "tag3",  "tag4") 
    | make-series agg_value = avg(value) default = double(null) on timestamp in range (datetime(2020-11-24 00:59:59), datetime(2020-11-24 12:00:00), 1s) by tag_name
    | extend series_fill_linear(agg_value, double(null), false) //EDIT
    | mv-expand timestamp to typeof(datetime), agg_value to typeof(double) 
    | summarize b = make_bag(pack(tag_name, agg_value)) by timestamp
    | evaluate bag_unpack(b)
|join kind = leftouter (label_data
    | where timestamp > datetime(2020-11-24 00:58:59) and timestamp <datetime(2020-11-24 12:00:01) 
    | where device_number =='PRESSURE_599'
    | where tag != "PRESSURE_599_label_Raw" 
    | summarize x = make_bag(pack(tag, value)) by timestamp
    | evaluate bag_unpack(x)) on timestamp
    | project timestamp, 
              MY_LINEAR_COL_1 = series_fill_linear(tag1, double(null), false),
              MY_LINEAR_COL_2 = series_fill_forward(tag2),
              MY_LABEL_1 = series_fill_forward(PRESSURE_599_label_level1),
              MY_LABEL_2 = series_fill_forward(PRESSURE_599_label_level2)
```

EDIT: I ended up using `extend` with `case` to handle different cases of interpolation.

// let forward_tags = dynamic({"tags": ["tag2","tag4"]}); unable to use this in query as "forward_tags.tags"

```
sensor_data
    | where timestamp > datetime(2020-11-24 00:59:59) and timestamp <datetime(2020-11-24 12:00:00)
    | where device_number = "PRESSURE_599"
    | where tag_name in ("tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4") // use a variable here instead?
    | make-series agg_value = avg(value) 
                              default = double(null) 
                              on timestamp
                              in range (datetime(2020-11-24 00:59:59), datetime(2020-11-24 12:00:00), 1s)
                              by tag_name
    | extend agg_value = case (tag_name in ("tag2", "tag3"), // use a variable here instead?
                                series_fill_forward(agg_value, double(null)),
                                series_fill_linear(agg_value, double(null), false)
                                )
    | mv-expand timestamp to typeof(datetime), agg_value to typeof(double) 
    | summarize b = make_bag(pack(tag_name, agg_value)) by timestamp
    | evaluate bag_unpack(b)
| join kind = leftouter (  
  label_data // don't want to use make-series here, will be unecessary data generation since already in 'ss' format.
    | where timestamp > datetime(2020-11-24 00:58:59) and timestamp <datetime(2020-11-24 12:00:01)
    | where tag != "PRESSURE_599_label_Raw" 
    | summarize x = make_bag(pack(tag, value)) by timestamp
    | evaluate bag_unpack(x)
    ) 
on timestamp
```

I was wondering if it is possible in `KQL` to pass a `list of strings` inside a query/fxn to use as shown below. I have commented where I think a `list of strings` could be passed to make the code more readable.

Now, I just need to `fill_forward` the label columns (`MY_LABEL_1, MY_LABEL_2`); which are a result of the below query. I would prefer the code is added on to the main query, and the final result is a table with all columns; Here is a sample table based on my case's result.

```
datatable (timestamp:datetime, tag1:double, tag2:double, tag3:double, tag4:double, MY_LABEL_1: string, MY_LABEL_2: string)
    [
     datetime(2020-11-24T00:01:00Z), 1, 3, 6, 9, "x", "foo",
     datetime(2020-11-24T00:01:01Z), 1, 3, 6, 9, "", "",
     datetime(2020-11-24T00:01:02Z), 1, 3, 6, 9,"", "",
     datetime(2020-11-24T00:01:03Z), 1, 3, 6, 9,"y", "bar",
     datetime(2020-11-24T00:01:04Z), 1, 3, 6, 9,"", "",
     datetime(2020-11-24T00:01:05Z), 1, 3, 6, 9,"", "",
     ]
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data in the form of datatable for the two datasets? This will make it easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: @Avnera sure, it will take some time for me to create tables, and they may not exactly align with real-data. I was able to interpolate in the above query by adding `extend series_fill_linear(..)` between `make-series` and `'mv-expand`. Please see in the code above. But this leads to interpolation of only one type on all my tags. So if just run separate queries depending on type of interpolation required -- the problem is probably solved. Performance is a separate matter for now; but still would prefer to be fexible in interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Series functions in ADX only work on dynamic arrays. You can apply a selective fill function using [case()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/casefunction) function, by replacing this line:

> `| extend series_fill_linear(agg_value, double(null), false) //EDIT`

With something like the following:

```
| extend agg_value = case(
        tag_name == "tag1", series_fill_linear(agg_value, double(null), false),
        tag_name == "tag2", series_fill_forward(agg_value),
        series_fill_forward(agg_value)
  )
```

**Edit**:
Here is an example of string column fill-forward workaround:

```
let T = datatable ( Timestamp: datetime, Employee: string ) 
[   datetime(2020-01-01), "Bob",
datetime(2021-01-02), "",
datetime(2021-01-03), "Alice",
datetime(2021-01-04), "",
datetime(2021-01-05), "",
datetime(2021-01-06), "Alan",
datetime(2021-01-07), "",
datetime(2021-01-08), ""  ]
| sort by Timestamp asc;
let employeeLookup = toscalar(T | where isnotempty(Employee) | summarize make_list(Employee));
T
| extend idx = row_cumsum(tolong(isnotempty(Employee)))
| extend EmployeeFilled = employeeLookup[idx - 1]
| project-away idx
```

| Timestamp | Employee | EmployeeFilled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | Bob | Bob |
| 2021-01-02 00:00:00.0000000 |  | Bob |
| 2021-01-03 00:00:00.0000000 | Alice | Alice |
| 2021-01-04 00:00:00.0000000 |  | Alice |
| 2021-01-05 00:00:00.0000000 |  | Alice |
| 2021-01-06 00:00:00.0000000 | Alan | Alan |
| 2021-01-07 00:00:00.0000000 |  | Alan |
| 2021-01-08 00:00:00.0000000 |  | Alan |

Comment: I had already implemented this while the question was posted. Please review my edited question for an update.

Comment: @pyeR_biz There is currently no way to fill forward a string column in KQL - such functionality is planned to be added in the future. Currently the only workaround is very cumbersome: build a lookup for the tag names and then use the lookup combined with row_cumsum() to fill the missing values (I've edited the answer to include an example of the workaround).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your requirement to convert the time series in many frequencies to a common one, have a look at [series_downsample_fl()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/functions-library/series-downsample-fl?tabs=adhoc) function library

Comment: That is interesting. Haven't come across it before. Might use it when I need to directly query ADX to plot. Current use case is data processing and requires a 1sec as it is representation.